# How to add external network using vSphere API

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I want to add external network using vSphere API but didn't got any idea.
Please give me links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Kindly check vSphere API documentation for details and procedures

There is an API service method:: **`AddVirtualNIC`**

```
 <element xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vim25="urn:vim25" name="AddVirtualNic" type="vim25:AddVirtualNicRequestType"/>
 <element xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vim25="urn:vim25" name="AddVirtualNicResponse">
    <complexType>
       <sequence>
          <element name="returnval" type="xsd:string"/>
       </sequence>
    </complexType>
 </element>
```

Proceed further with configuration details on [vSphere HostNetworkSystem <*ManagedOBJECT*>](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.host.NetworkSystem.html)